# Warnings "unchecked call" and "unchecked conversion"

Tags: java, generics, warnings

**When I compile my code I get 4 warnings - but how do I make them disappear?** 
(and I don't mean with @SuppressWarnings)

PS: Obviously this must have been asked before - but either I cannot find it or I cannot apply it.

---

***Output***

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to BaseWorker(C) as a member of the raw type BaseWorker
[warn] return new BaseWorker(this);

warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
[warn] found   : com.crashnote.BaseWorker
[warn] required: com.crashnote.BaseWorker<C>
[warn] return new BaseWorker(this);

warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to SubWorker(C) as a member of the raw type SubWorker
[warn] return new SubWorker(this);

warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
[warn] found   : com.crashnote.SubWorker
[warn] required: com.crashnote.SubWorker<C>
[warn] return new SubWorker(this);
```

---

***Source Code***

**BaseConfig**: instantiates *BaseWorker*

```
public class BaseConfig<C extends BaseConfig> {

    public BaseConfig(final Object c) {
    }

    public BaseWorker<C> getWorker() {
        return new BaseWorker(this);
    }
}
```

**BaseWorker**

```
public class BaseWorker<C extends BaseConfig> {

    public BaseWorker(final C config) {
    }
}
```

**SubConfig**: instantiates *SubWorker*

```
class SubConfig<C extends SubConfig> extends BaseConfig<C> {

    public SubConfig(final Object c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public SubWorker<C> getWorker() {
        return new SubWorker(this);
    }
}
```

**SubWorker**: inherits from SubWorker

```
public class SubWorker<C extends BaseConfig> extends BaseWorker<C> {

      public SubWorker(final C config) {
          super(config);
      }  
}
```

---

***Edit***

I tried the provided solutions but for some reason it fails now.

**A)**

```
return new BaseWorker<BaseConfig>(this);
```

results in

```
incompatible types
[error] found   : BaseWorker<BaseConfig>
[error] required: BaseWorker<C>
[error] return new BaseWorker<BaseConfig>(this);
```

**B)**

```
return new BaseWorker<C>(this);
```

results in

```
cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : constructor BaseWorker(BaseConfig<C>)
[error] location: class BaseWorker<C>
[error] return new BaseWorker<C>(this);
```

Hm, maybe I'm doing something wrong. This is Java 6 by the way, in case it matters.

Comment: You need to supply generic parameter to the constructor:
`return new BaseWorker<BaseConfig>(this);`

Comment: you miss the generics in all constructor calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after applying the answers to my code I found out that they are actually wrong. Here is what seems to work.

**BaseConfig** now has a print() method (just to check we have the right type later) and adds a generic  to the instantiation of *BaseWorker*.

```
public class BaseConfig<C extends BaseConfig> {

    public BaseConfig(final Object c) {
    }

    public BaseWorker<C> getWorker() {
        return new BaseWorker<C>(this);
    }

    public void print() {
        //
    }
}
```

Now this is where it gets interesting, **BaseWorker** has a constructor with a generic. This seems totally redundant - but it was the only way I found that worked. When you write just `<C>` it appears to be a new "local" generic additionally to the one of the class and a compiler error is raised (`cannot find symbol: method print()`).

```
public class BaseWorker<C extends BaseConfig> {

    public <C extends BaseConfig> BaseWorker(final C config) {
        config.print();
    }
}
```

**SubConfig** and **SubWorker** are changed accordingly.

PS: If this is utter nonsense please tell me :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning plain

```
return new BaseWorker(this);
```

Make it generic, because your `BaseWorker` class is defined as generic.

```
return new BaseWorker<C>(this);
```

Same rule applies for `SubWorker` also.

```
return new SubWorker<C>(this);
```

**Update:**

Based on exception message, your constructor also missing generics.

Comment: Based on exception message, your constructor also missing generics.

Comment: Updated answer. Good luck with coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 return new BaseWorker<C>(this);
```

and

```
 return new SubWorker<C>(this);
```